# Error when trying to search for words through queries - Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to search for words through queries but it gives me this message:
[image]

[image]

The problem occurs when writing this code

```
const search = String(req.query.keyword)
  if (req.query.keyword) {
    req.query.keyword = req.query.keyword.split("%22").join(" ");
    console.log(req.query.keyword)
    const query = {};
    query.$or = [
      {title: { $regex: search, $options : 'i' }},
      {description: { $regex: search, $options : 'i' }}
    ];
    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.find(query)
  }
```

Comment: mongodb doesn't return http status codes, which line is called out by the error?

Comment: You can review the images. I think the problem is in receiving the query in string form

Comment: Can you post the *full* function code?

Comment: Please [don't post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code again and the solution to the problem is to replace the if with this code

```js
.find(req.query.keyword ? query : {}) 
    
const query = {};
query.$or = [
  { title: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" } },
  { description: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" } },
];
```